# Flutter Background Process even App Closed

Tags: flutter, background, alarm

I want to build an app that gives me location alarms when I enter a certain area. I've implemented geolocation to get the current position and I want to check if I am at the right coordinates in real-time.

I've been looking around to the Android Alarm Manager package to achieve that goal. But I couldn't run the code in the background while the app closed.

My question is a standard alarm app check the time constantly and trigger a notification? I mean is my approach a bad solution, should I check the position every second? Or what else can be done to check current position?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's way harder than you think. I'd recommend you should be using this: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_geolocation

However, it's paid. I am not affiliated with them.